# Sanatize input to include whitespace in regex?

Tags: python, regex, escaping, python-re

I'm using python 3.5 currently.

I am trying to make a tool that takes input, and does a regex search for said "Playername" and returns the matching result. I run into an interesting issue because this is videogame related, and some users have special characters in their names (Clan Tags).

To try to sanitize input, I am using `re.escape`, but I am not getting the behavior I expected out of it.

Example, I am allowing users to input partial matches, and use regex to find a player. So if I input `Mall`, it should be able to regex to find `Mallachar`, her is my current example matching setup.

```
regex_match = r".*" + player_name + r".*"

if re.match(regex_match, str(name_list), re.IGNORECASE):
    player_list.append(players)
```

Because this is a system where user names are not unique, and a player can change their name, I am searching against a "list" of users.

Anyways, the issue I am running into is when people have spaces or clan tags. Example, if the clan `~DOG~` joins the server, and I have people with names `~DOG~ Master` and `~DOG- Runner`, if I feed in the string `~DOG~ Run`, I get all matches to `~DOG~ .*`.

My understanding is that `re.escape` should be escaping the space so it's a part of my search, so it should be trying to match this

```
.*~DOG~\sRun.*
```

But instead it seems to be running this, like it's ignoring everything after `~DOG~`:

```
.*~DOG~.*
```

Am I misunderstanding how `re.escape` is?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in` operator to check if `player_name` is inside other string:

```
name_list = ['~DOG~ Master', '~DOG~ Runner']
player_name = '~DOG~ Run'

player_list = []
for name in name_list:
    if player_name in name:
        player_list.append(name)

print(player_list)
```

This prints:

```
['~DOG~ Runner']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `in` is probably the right way to solve this problem but on the use of regex question itself.

Adding a set of parens will let you use matches

```
python so_post.py
('~DOG~ Run',)
alexl@MBP000413 ~ :)% cat so_post.py
import re
regex_match = r".*(~DOG~ Run).*"
name = "~DOG~ Run"

match =  re.match(regex_match, name, re.IGNORECASE)
print(match.groups())
```

Using named groups lets you use a specific name instead of just a general tuple of matches.

```
regex_match = r".*(?P<user_clan>~DOG~ Run).*"
name = "~DOG~ Run"

match =  re.match(regex_match, name, re.IGNORECASE)
print(match.groups("user_clan"))
```

Comment: I wrote this a year ago... and I can't seem to remember why I chose regex instead of in. I will test this out. thanks!